# Memory efficient lexical analysis with iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I've been trying to design a lexer (for a programming language) that doesn't accumulate tokens in an intermediate list. This should be simple enough, and in C++ I figured this was a good use of iterators (I'm no expert at C++ by the way). That being said, I can't quite seem to find a satisfactory solution to the problem. This is the most logical thing I could come up with in the context of iterators:

```
enum class symbol {
  IDENTIFIER,
  ...
};
struct token {
  symbol symbol;
  std::string::const_iterator lexeme_begin;
  std::string::const_iterator lexeme_end;
};
class lexer {
private:
  std::string::const_iterator begin_, end_;
public:
  lexer(
      std::string::const_iterator begin,
      std::string::const_iterator end) :
      begin_ {begin}, end_ {end} {};
  class iterator;
  iterator begin() {
    return {begin_, end_};
  }
  iterator end() {
    // Can't figure out what to do here.
  }
};
class lexer::iterator {
private:
  std::string::const_iterator begin_, end_, next_;
public:
  iterator(
      std::string::const_iterator begin,
      std::string::const_iterator end) :
      begin_ {begin}, end_ {end} {};
  iterator operator++() {
    if (_next == _end) {
      // Same problem as in lexer::end.
    }
    _begin = _next;
    return *this;
  }
  token operator*() {
    // Perform actual lexical analysis here.
  }
};
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
for (auto token : lexer {"abc 123"}) {
  std::cout << token;
}
```

My question is: Is this an appropriate use of iterators, and if so, how would I handle the `lexer::end()` iterator. The only way I could think to implement `lexer::end()` is by returning a special instance of `lexer::iterator`, but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me. The other thing that bothers me a little bit is that each iterator has to contain the same iterator to the end of the string, though this seems much less of a problem.

Comment: Lexical analysers never 'accumulate tokens in an intermediate list'. They return one token at a time to a parser. I don't consider this is a good case for using an iterator at all, especially a C++ iterator, as the lexer has no good concept of `end().`

Comment: @EJP I tend to agree with you, but do you know if the standard library facilitates anything else for this purpose? I could create a generator-like interface for the class but I didn't want to recreate the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not implementing my lexical analyzer with a custom interface instead of an iterator. My confusion was that I was using a C++ iterators as if it were a generator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming). For simple input parsing, the standard library provides input streams (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), but for more robust parsing I would recommend using a parsing library such as boost's spirit or simply writing your own custom interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like a reasonable place to use iterators. I haven't seen a lexer built quite like this, but it looks plausible.

To me, there is no objection to having a distinguished instance of lexer as the value of end(). It's often convenient for a lexer to return an EOF token that isn't really in the source code, and that's in effect the value of end(). Could well be a static.

I don't really understand why you need a class and a nested class to express the basic tokenisation logic. What you've shown us here is missing all the interesting stuff about actually delivering tokens, and seems overkill for a simple tokeniser and iterator support.

I'm guessing that your begin/end/next iterators serve the purpose of pointers into a stream of characters, so I don't understand `each iterator has to contain the same iterator to the end of the string`.